# how to reference a component without it being rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-functional-component

so im using react-to-print library it has a content: prop which takes a reference for a element, component,

```
 const componentRef = useRef();
  const print = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });
  <SecondaryInvoice
        data={sender.order && senders.order.order}
        ref={componentRef}
      />
```

but the problem is this SecondaryInvoice  is not being rendered because I dont need to.

I have also used forwardRef in the SecondaryInvoice to pass the reference

```
const SecondaryInvoice = React.forwardRef(({data}, ref) => {
  return (
    <> ....
```

How can I acheive this?
Thanks

Comment: You could give it a prop render={false} and if render is false then dont render anything in that component

Comment: @kevin my problem is not that, I have that SecondaryInvocie component which is a invoice that will need to be printed when a order is submited, I want it to be rendered(because its html code) and I dont want it to be visible at the same time, so like kinda runs in the background, and I cant set display to none or any css property, because im passing that html to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

okay found a way, it works, couldnt find a better way, hopefully someone finds it useful if one day faced same problem,

I put the Component in parent component , that means it is rendering now

```
 return (
    <>
  <SecondaryInvoice
    data={senders.order && senders.order.order}
    ref={componentRef}
     </>
```

give it a class, and then let it have opacity of zero and height of 0, you cant use display none, and then when printing it, set the height back to 100% and opcaity to 1 in the @print media query

```
 .secondary-invoice {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px !important;
}

@media print {
  .secondary-invoice {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
```